# Can I Combine Areas in Quantum GIS?

Tags: qgis

I am working on a provincial annual health bulletin.

I have a .shp file that has GIS data about the smallest divisions called "GN Area". Two or three GN Areas form one MOH area. I want to get the MOH area details displayed in the map. How can I do it? I am using QGIS.

Is there any way where GN Area data exported to excel and add the relevant MOH area and import it back to Quantum GIS and display MOH Areas rather than GN ares?

If that is not possible with Quantum GIS, is there any other method to do it?

Answer (score 6):

Add a new field to your shapefile, call it MOH_Area.  Enter in all the MOH_Areas.  Then dissolve on the MOH_Areas field.  This will give you a new shapefile showing the MOH_Area boundaries.

Dissolve is located inside geoprocessing tools.

Answer (score 1):

This is an aggregation called dissolve. You can do it in `QGIS` with the `ftools` plugin. <s>Go to Plugins->Fetch Python Plugins and search for `ftools`.</s>

EDIT:
The ftools plugin ship with QGIS; it just needs to be enabled in the `Plugins`-menu. Then, go to the `Vector` menu, pick `Geoprocessing Tools`, select `Dissolve` and select the proper inputs. The dissolve field would be `MOH Area` in your case.

Comment: fTools is installed by default and ships with QGIS.  Just go to `Plugins->Manage Plugins..` to enable.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was not entirely sure whether that was "batteries included".